# C++ pointer showing impossible memory location

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, size, diskspace

I made a C++ variable and printed its address and it came out to be very large: 0x7ffdf584da2c.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int var = 10;
    cout << "value: " << var << " address: " << &var << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`value: 10 address: 0x7ffec6f111c4`

This type of Hexadecimal memory address (0x7ffdf584da2c) looks impossible as its Decimal comes out to be (140728722577964) which is fairly large for my laptop. 
I've a dual boot laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu and Memory around 500 GB. The code is written in Ubuntu.

Comment: This might help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: Virtual memory addresses can easily be larger than what's *physically* addressable in your machine. The OS kernel will take care of mapping virtual addresses to physical ones. Don't worry about the absolute values.

Comment: 500 GB RAM in a laptop would be pretty impressive. You might be mixing up RAM with hard disk capacity. Where this gets really neat, though, is through the magic of virtual memory your hard disk can be used as extra storage for stuff in memory that's currently not needed to be in RAM. Or you've run out of RAM and get to experience the [joys of Thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).

Comment: There is also this: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: @drescherjm you beat me by 4 seconds!

Comment: In the time of DOS, CP/M and similar; the addresses you got back from allocations were physical addresses. That has not been the case for more than 2-3 decades. With modern operating systems and virtual memory. These days, the OS will give you back an address that is (for all intents and purposes) random. You can use it to access the memory you allocated, but it tells you *nothing* about the physical memory layout of the machine you are running on.

Comment: Thank you @JesperJuhl and all who commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine.

Computers in 2020 are very complicated. Your process gets a [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) whose maximum "slot" will almost certainly exceed the size of the actual RAM on your system (and page file).

Comment: Thank you very much, @Asteroid With Wings. Jesper's comment is very insightful too :)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the stack which goes from top of memory (not actual memory but what the operating system handles) to bottom. So normally if begins at a high value limited by OS and architecture bits (32, 64, ...).

Comment: This answer is either misusing the term "stack" and needs to be reworded or is wrong and needs to be corrected.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't see anything wrong with this answer.  Local variables in C and C++ are normally allocated on the stack, and stack pointers generally start at a high value and go down as more is allocated.  None of this is guaranteed, but it is typically how it works.